# See stdout when running bash script in PyCharm

Tags: python, bash, stdout, pycharm

I use a bash script to call several python scripts. I installed the bash plugin for PyCharm. I can run the script, but I don't see stdout during runtime, even though I see it after everything finished. How can I make that visible during runtime?

Comment: Can you share the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all of the required information, my guess would be that this is due to Python buffering its output, which is its default behavior. You can easily disable this by passing python the `-u` flag or by setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable.

This is described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/40076).

Comment: Ok, that did it. Thanks! But why doesn't it happen when I run the same script in the shell?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "running the script in the shell", its one of the following: 1) Python knows when it's in interactive mode, and disables output buffering in that case. 2) PyCharm probably knows to run Python without output buffering when one uses a Python run configuration.